# Are PHP namespaces used with a leading slash

Tags: php, namespaces

When using `PHP` **namespaces**, do you use them like:

```
\Foo\Bar->method()
```

or

```
Foo\Bar->method()
```

Notice the difference is only a leading slash. Or are both valid, and mean different things?

Thanks.

Comment: Top one is for [global namespace](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.global.php) (with syntax fixed).

Answer (score 8):

The usage of a leading `\` is like absolute and relative paths in filesystems. Best explained with code:

```
namespace test;
$dt = new DateTime();
```

fails, as we are using an relative path (without the leading `\`), and the current namespace `test`. And there is not class `DateTime` in this fictional namespace.

```
namespace test;
$dt = new \DateTime();
```

works as we are using an absolute namespaces path. As `DateTime` is in the global namespace `\` it will be found.

Find more info in the [PHP manual about namespaces](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php)

Answer (score 2):

It depends on your needs.

```
\Foo\Bar::method(); // will search class in root namespace
```

or

```
Foo\Bar::method(); // will search class in current namespace
```

Both expression are valid. But doing different things.